# What is causing 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError' while using 'summary' on a joined PySpark DataFrame of CSV and Hive tables?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

While doing comparisons using summary function in pyspark, machine throws:

> "Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-10" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

I am working with 2 tables, one in Hive and another one is a CSV,Code being used is:

```py
#Read the DF from HIVE
df = spark\
    .sql("COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5","COL6","COL7" FROM db.table")
```

And here i think lies the problem, I am reading a csv file using PANDAS then turning it into a spark DF to then do a join and use the summary to show me some stats about the columns:

```py
#Read the csv file
df2 = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df_sas = spark.createDataFrame(df2)

#Join the 2 DFs
df_final = df_sas.alias("a").join(df.alias('b'), df_sas.ID == df.ID,'inner')\
    .select('a.*','b.*')

#Generate the summary
df_final.select('a.COL1').filter(col('a.COL1') != 0).summary().show()
```

Both tables have the same columns.

The join is needed since the tables has different populations and we are only comparing the ID's that are in both tables at the same time.